# How to align text in the middle beside a canvas element

Tags: html, css

i need my text elements to be in the middle of the div and beside my canvas element. currently, the texts are beside but aren't in the middle. how can i achieve this effect?

Btw, the canvas contains a chart plugin which i did not include in the code snippets below.

```css
#user-count {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.card {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border: none;
  padding:10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.card-body {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="card">
    <canvas id="user-count"></canvas>
     <div class="card-body">
      <span>current blood donors</span>
      <span>as of 2017</span>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this css..

```
#user-count {
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: i feel so dumb, i was putting this in .card and .card-body, but thank you this worked!

Answer (score 1):

Something like that with Flex :)

```css
#user-count {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.card {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card-body {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
      <canvas id="user-count">
          </canvas>
      <div class="card-body">
        <span>current blood donors</span>
        <span>as of 2017</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't know why you did ```justify-content```

Answer (score 0):

```
.card {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

So you can use display:flex instead of inline-block. flex is a bit similar to inline-block but not same and use align-items:center which centers all element to center vertically